# flutter_vpn example app crashing after installing

Tags: android, flutter, vpn, strongswan

I was trying to build a vpn app in flutter then I found the [flutter_vpn](https://github.com/X-dea/flutter_vpn) package which is using strongswan vpn protocol but when I tried to run the example app in the library in debug mode, it runs fine without any problem. But when I tried to build apk or run in release mode the app crashes immediately. Can any one help me please. I created an [issue](https://github.com/X-dea/flutter_vpn/issues/80) in github
where you can find the error log.

Thank you

Comment: Just a guess, did you add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the Android manifest?

Comment: Yes, it is added in the Android manifest. The app installs then comes the black screen and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the real fix or not but this fixes the problem

```
release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    minifyEnabled false
    shrinkResources false
}
```